# Calculate time taken to reduce drug level to 30 percent of original level

Tags: integration

So i calculated a differential equation when the quantity of drug remaining in a patient's body decreases at a rate proportional to the quantity remaining. Supposing the half life of the drug is 35 hrs.

$$\frac{\mathrm d Q}{\mathrm d t}=−\frac{\ln(2)}{35}Q$$

I want to find the time it takes to for the drug to reduce to 30% of its original level. I dont know how to move on from here. Where do we substitute the 30.

Comment: You have the rate equation , form an exponential decay equation for $Q$, that should be it. You can refer to the internet as "first order chemical kinetics"

Comment: That difEQ is separable, just divide each side by Q and integrate both sides.

Comment: Also refer to the usage of mathjax http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference